# Performing actions with method returned values

Tags: c#, class, methods, return

I have class: class_getanswer and class: class_performaction
in class_getanswer i have method:

```
class class_getanswer
{
    static public int capacity()
    {
        Random block = new Random();
        int beta = block.Next(1, 8);
        return beta;
    }
}
```

in class with method Main i want that answer to be in function if:

```
class class_performaction
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int value = 5;
        if(class_getanswer.capacity() < value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bla bla bla");
        }
    }
}
```

but i get that "if" doesn't exist in this context, why?

There is screenshot of kinda full programm but in different language (lithuanian): https://www.dropbox.com/s/jggwgt738vltawx/functionswt.PNG?dl=0

Comment: your if statement is capitalized. it shouldn't be

Comment: I believe i just fixed your Error while reformatting your code! You need to put `()` after `static void Main` and write your `If` with a lowercase `i`

Comment: Are you really prefixing your class names with 'class_'?

Comment: Sorry not enough sleep :/ i got used to write from capital letter. 
no i don't name classes class_... i named them for this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the case of, if statement. I believe you wrote If(with a capital 'I'), change it to small case 'i'.